# How can I customize the OS login/password prompt in Linux?

Tags: linux

When I log in to Linux, this is the prompt I see:

```
login:  
Password:
```

I want to change it to:

```
Please enter the username:  
Please enter password:
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Linux always needed to be a little more polite! ;-)

Comment: What distro(version) of Linux are you using?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you can't do this easily. A quick look through the source for `agetty` (at least on my Debian box here) suggests that `login:` is hardcoded in, so you'd need to make changes to the `getty` source and recompile it.

For the password, again a quick look through the source for `pam_unix.so` suggests that `Password:` is hard-coded in there, so you would need to make changes to the source for that and recompile.